# Changing list column to a choice

Tags: content-type, column, site-column, choice-field

I have a list populated with content type ("TypeA") with a column (site column "ColB") that originally was a single line of text.  I needed to change the column to a choice instead of a single line of text.

In Site Columns, I changed "ColB" to Choice and added the options.  No problem.
In Content Types, I changed "ColB" to Choice (or it changed automatically, can't remember).  No problem.
In the listsetting, "ColB" is still listed as Single line of text.  Tried to change it in both SP Designer and in the web UI, but saving changes fails both ways, and "ColB" stays as a single line of text.  (And the list forms still show a plain textbox for the editor)

What did I do wrong?  How can I fix this to make "ColB" a choice?

Answer (score 2):

Finally hunted down the error:  I had the column indexed.  Once I removed the index, it changed nicely, then I re-added the index.

Comment: User should update the content type with new site column as well. This is also the solution for it.  Mentioned in my solution. BTW You did the exact thing by removing it from index so it will gets you the updated reference for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using either **PowerShell** or the **SharePoint UI**, Just add a site column to the content type, remove it, and then add it again.

it propagates properly.